# Discarding matzas according to Jewish law

Tags: matzah, disposal

Where I work has a no-gifts policy, however someone unknown deposited two new boxes of matza in the waiting-room.

Is there a proper way to deal with these following Jewish law? None of us can use them, since that would be considered accepting them as gifts.

Answer (score 3):

Matzot (plural of matza) have no inherent sanctity. As such, you can treat these boxes as you would treat two new boxes of cookies that were left in the waiting room. You can give them away, open them and eat them, discard them, etc.

Judaism doesn't like wasting valuable things (it is called Bal Tashchit, see [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1892179/jewish/Judaism-and-Environmentalism-Bal-Tashchit.htm) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bal_tashchit)) but two boxes of matzot are not that highly valuable and fewer people will want to eat them after Passover.

Nevertheless, it would be great if you found a productive use for them. Maybe leave them in the waiting room with a sign that whoever wants them is welcome to take them home?

Comment: Inclusion of evidence for its first two sentences would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: @msh210 it is hard to prove a negative. I thought again about it but am not sure how to do this. Does the absence of Google results count?

Comment: Perhaps a _kal vachomer_ from _Orach Chayim_ 21:1?

Comment: @msh210 I'm not sure that is valid. First because even the matza on the seder plate (analogy with *tzitzit* being worn?) is not sacred per se. But other food is (e.g., *teruma*). Not sure the analogy works but will think further